# setting the id attribute of an input element dynamically in IE: alternative for setAttribute method

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm looking at dynamically setting the ID attribute of HTML Input elements which are created dynamically in my application.

My implementation works fine with the setAttribute method in Firefox. Any ideas or solutions on a working implementation in IE would be appreciated.

```
 var hiddenInput = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenInput.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
    hiddenInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");                     
    hiddenInput.setAttribute("value", ID);
    hiddenInput.setAttribute("class", "ListItem");
```

I modified some sample code from blogs relating to this problem that suggest the following workround. Again the Firefox bit works well but the IE bit doens't

```
var hiddenInput = null;

try { 
hiddenInput  = document.createElement('<input name=\''+"hiddenInputName"+'\'   />');
                    hiddenInput.id = "uniqueIdentifier";
                    //alert(document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier")); 
                   hiddenInput.type = "hidden";
                } catch (e) { }            
                if (!hiddenInput || !hiddenInput.name) { // Not in IE, then
                     var hiddenInput = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenInput.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
    hiddenInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");                     

            }
```

Cheers.

Comment: Which version of IE do you test on?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is there an error message? What goes wrong?

Comment: When I invoke alert -un-comment alert(document.getElementByID("uniqueIdentifier")); in the try block- it returns null object. Hence the assignment of an id attribute- hiddenInput.id = "uniqueIdentifier"- isn't working for me in IE8. I wondering why that is?

Comment: @Terman: At the point at which that `alert()` is called, the input is not yet in the document, hence the `document.getElementById()` call returns null. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks All,  for your comments and contributions. I ended up discarding the setAttribute() approach and leveraging the innerHTML property. Cheers

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This [code](http://jsfiddle.net/5EqT2/) work in IE7 and Chrome:

```
var hiddenInput = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenInput.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
    hiddenInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");                     
    hiddenInput.setAttribute("value", 'ID');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute("class", "ListItem");

$('body').append(hiddenInput);
```

Maybe problem somewhere else ?

Comment: Quick Note: old IE versions do have some issues with a few items... a.) you can't set the `name` attribute with `setAttribute()`, and b.) you can't set the `type` attribute once you've added it to the DOM (it becomes readonly) c.) to set the class, you'll need to set "className" details here: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-242-setattribute-doesnt-always-work.html and fixes to IE are only on pages rendered in Standards mode.

Answer (score 67):

Forget `setAttribute()`: it's badly broken and doesn't always do what you might expect in old IE (IE <= 8 and compatibility modes in later versions). Use the element's properties instead. This is generally a good idea, not just for this particular case. Replace your code with the following, which will work in all major browsers:

```
var hiddenInput = document.createElement("input");
hiddenInput.id = "uniqueIdentifier";
hiddenInput.type = "hidden";                     
hiddenInput.value = ID;
hiddenInput.className = "ListItem";
```

**Update**

The nasty hack in the second code block in the question is unnecessary, and the code above works fine in all major browsers, including IE 6. See http://www.jsfiddle.net/timdown/aEvUT/. The reason why you get `null` in your `alert()` is that when it is called, the new input is not yet in the document, hence the `document.getElementById()` call cannot find it.

Comment: Cheers. Almost seems like I've already tried that but I'll give it a go

Comment: @Tim Down      Sorry to interrupt you. But as I write the code var hiddenInput = document.createElement("input"); hiddenInput.id = "uniqueIdentifier"; on Chrome Browser, the Console Log only shows me
"uniqueIdentifier" without the element <input>. So as I use $('#uniqueIdentifier').prop("id") ---> The console tells me "undefined". In my opinion, document.createElement("input") has already create an element: "input", and thus we give it an id, doesn't it? Why this happen? Thanks.

Comment: @Tim Down, I think `ID` needs quotes around it to work, unless there is something I'm missing? Great answer though. Is it safe to say that this is still a better method than using `setAttribute()`?

Comment: @pixel67: `ID` comes directly from the question, which seems to imply the existence of a variable called `ID` that is defined elsewhere. As to whether it's still a better idea to use the property rather than the attribute, I'd still say so. The only thing that has changed is that old IE has become less prevalent (but is not yet entirely dead, sadly). The other advantages of using a property still exist: brevity, clarity, convenience. Compare `input.disabled = true` to `input.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")`, for example.

Answer (score 6):

Use jquery [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method. It works in all browsers.

```
var hiddenInput = document.createElement("input");
$(hiddenInput).attr({
    'id':'uniqueIdentifier',
    'type': 'hidden',
    'value': ID,
    'class': 'ListItem'
});
```

Or you could use folowing code:

```
var e = $('<input id = "uniqueIdentifier" type="hidden" value="' + ID + '" class="ListItem" />');
```

Comment: interesting, by checking code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js, it's already on version `1.5.0` :) Looks like its gonna be released pretty soon.

Comment: Thanks. I'd use a JavaScript toolkit -I appreciate JQuery- but I'm a bit constrained in that the site I'm working on doesn't leverage jQuery much, and I'm just trying to keep consistent.

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't aware of a problem with `setAttribute` in IE ? However you could directly set the expando property on the node itself:

```
hiddenInput.id = "uniqueIdentifier";
```

Comment: Assigning the ID directly doesn't seem to work for me. For instance after an assignment I'd invoke alert(document.getElementByID("uniqueIdentifier")); and it returns null :=( thanks

Comment: `id` is not an expando, it's a DOM property. IE's `setAttribute()` implementation is badly broken: in general, it maps attributes to properties. This means that the "class" attribute doesn't work correctly, for example: the equivalent property is `className`. It also means event handler attributes don't work, since `setAttribute()` should expect a string attribute value but event handler properties must be function objects.

Comment: @TimDown: Ah thanks for the clarification. Well, `.id` is a "DOM property" but isnt it an object property in ECMALand at the same time ?

Comment: It's a property of a host object, so yes. My point is that "expando" has a particular meaning for DOM elements in IE, which is an arbitrary user-defined property on the element. `unselectable` is implemented as an expando in IE. There is some information on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, which relates to the `document.expando` property, which can be used to disable the ability to add expandos anywhere in the document.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute) says:

> When you need to set attributes that are also mapped to a JavaScript dot-property (such as href, style, src or event-handlers), favour that mapping instead.

So, just change **id**, **value** assignment and you should be done.

Comment: "The documentation"? You mean one site that neither defines standards or implements them (namely, Sitepoint). I do happen to agree with it though.

Comment: Ok it is not **official** documentation, but they describe this problem well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue! I was unable to change/set the ID attribute of elements. It worked in all other browsers but not IE. It probably isn't relevant to your problem but here is what I ended up doing:

**Background**

I was building an MVC site with jquery tabs. I wanted to create tabs dynamically and do an AJAX postback to the server saving the tab in the database. I wanted to use a unique identifier, in the form of an int, for the tabs so I wouldn't get in to trouble if a user created two tabs with the same name. I then used the unique ID to identify the tabs like:

```
<ul>
<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove List</span></li>
<ul>
```

When I then implemented the remove functions on the tabs the callback uses the index, witch is 0 based. Then I had no way to sending back the unique ID to the server to trash the DB entry. The callback for the tabremove event gives the jquery event and ui parameters. With one line of code I could get the ID of the span:

```
var dbIndex = event.currentTarget.id;
```

The problem was that the span tag didn't have any ID. So in the create callback I tried to set the ID buy extracting the ID from the a href like this:

```
ui.tab.parentNode.id = ui.tab.href.substring(ui.tab.href.indexOf('#list-') + 6);
```

That worked fine in FireFox but not in IE. So I tried a few other:

```
//ui.tab.parentNode.setAttribute('id', ui.tab.href.substring(ui.tab.href.indexOf('#list-') + 6));
//$(ui.tab.parentNode).attr({'id':ui.tab.href.substring(ui.tab.href.indexOf('#list-') + 6)});
//ui.tab.parentNode.id.value = ui.tab.href.substring(ui.tab.href.indexOf('#list-') + 6);
```

None of them worked! So after a few hours of test and Googeling I gave up and draw the conclusion that IE cant set the ID attribute of an element dynamically.

As I sad this is probably not relevant to your issue but I thought I would share.

**Solution**

And for all of you who found this by Googleing on the tabs issue I had here is what I ended up doing in the tabsremove callback to solve the issue:

```
var dbIndex = event.currentTarget.offsetParent.childNodes[0].href.substring(event.currentTarget.offsetParent.childNodes[0].href.indexOf('#list-') + 6);
```

Probably not the sexiest solution but hey it solved the issue. If anyone have any input please share...