# Changing attribute of dynamically generated tags with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to rewrite `src` and/or `href` attribute of tags on a page using Jquery. I have tried this [sample code.](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) It works for tags which are already in the html page, however for tags dynamically generated by Javascript it does not work.

Any solution for this kind of requirement that every time tags are generated like `img` tag I need to change it's attribute.

Sample Code:

```
<script>
$("img").attr({ 
  src: "/images/hat.gif",
  title: "jQuery",
  alt: "jQuery Logo"
});
$("div").text($("img").attr("alt"));
</script>
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder He hasn't referred to any code? OMGWTFBBQ?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851699/setting-the-id-attribute-of-an-input-element-dynamically-in-ie-alternative-for

Comment: lol... he's showing something from the docs LMAO

Comment: You should proberbly consider making a imageCustomize function, you can call when inserting images, because hooking into all functions is a bad idea. Don't you have accces to the code that inserts the images?

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen actually I'm just putting the image as sample, its not just image I need to manipuate, almost all kind of tags in a html page.

Comment: Well basicly you can't do that, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068955/jquery-function-after-append) .. And it's not the best idea to "insert data to dom, the change the inserted data in the dom", so if you can - change it in the insert :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see on your code is that you are generating the img element twice... you should keep the reference to the element you create the first time.

Like this:

```
<script>
var myImage = $("img").attr({ 
  src: "/images/hat.gif",
  title: "jQuery",
  alt: "jQuery Logo"
});
$("div").text(myImage.attr("alt"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
$('#id_of_element_to_change').attr("src")="path/src_or_href";
```

Comment: Thanks, however my script would not know the ID of the element. Is there a way to iterate on all tags and get its id? Also, will it work for every time tags are dynamically injected in the page?