# Can't change inner HTML

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function order(){
var i = 1;
while(i != 0){
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("taska"+i)!=null){
        var p1 = sessionStorage.getItem("taska"+i);
        var p2 = sessionStorage.getItem("price"+i);

        var a = document.createElement('td');
            a.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("id"+i);
        var b = document.createElement('td');
            var b1 = document.createElement('img');
                b1.src = '/obrazky/taska_'+p1+'.png';
            b.appendChild(b1);
        var c = document.createElement('td');
            c.innerHTML = p1;
        var d = document.createElement('td');
            d.innerHTML = ''+p2+' Kč';
        var e = document.createElement('td');
            var e1 = document.createElement('input');
                e1.type = 'number';
                e1.setAttribute("id", i);
                e1.onclick = totalPrice(this);
            e.appendChild(e1);
        var f = document.createElement('td');
            f.setAttribute("id", "total"+i);
            f.innerHTML = ''+p2+' Kč';


        document.getElementById('tr'+i).appendChild(a);
        document.getElementById('tr'+i).appendChild(b);
        document.getElementById('tr'+i).appendChild(c);
        document.getElementById('tr'+i).appendChild(d);
        document.getElementById('tr'+i).appendChild(e);
        document.getElementById('tr'+i).appendChild(f);
        i++;
    }else{
        i=0;
    }
}
}
function totalPrice(nofitems){
    var x = nofitems.id;
    var y = nofitems.value*Number(sessionStorage.getItem("price"+x));
    document.getElementById('total'+x).innerHTML = y+' Kč';
}
```

I've created function order to insert some html elements. I want to change the element var f when qty of the item is increased. I'm using the totalPrice function to do this, but whenever it's calledm, the console pops up:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

I think, that it isn't able to find the created element by id.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see any elements with id 'tr' being added in your order function. Does it already exist on the page?

Comment: Yes it does. It's in the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first, I see something is not right in this line of code:

```
  e1.onclick = totalPrice(this);
```

this will not attach `totalPrice` function to the onclick event of the e1 element. Also, the keyword `this` in the current context refers to the window object, so there is no meaning to send it as a parameter to the `totalPrice` function It should be like this instead:

```
e1.onclick = totalPrice;
```

You should also adjust your totalPrice function to get the totalnumber of items and calculate the price accordingly

Edit: the function shall look like this

```
function totalPrice(){
    var x = this.id;
    var y = this.value*Number(sessionStorage.getItem("price"+x));
    document.getElementById('total'+x).innerHTML = y+' Kč';
}
```

Comment: But how do I get the right element in totalPrice() then? There will be more elements like e1.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I should have mentioned it. I have created the tr+i element in html code.

Comment: In the `totalPrice` function, `this` keyword would refer to the element that received the click

Comment: And that would be the var f element, which I wanted. But it doesn't work.

Comment: the event is attached to the input element `e1` not on `f`

Comment: Sorry, I meant var e1.

Comment: You should also change the totalPrice function to use the keyword `this` to refer the element that received the click (i.e the input element). I have updated my answer accordingly. Please check it

Comment: Thank you very much. You are my savior :)

Answer (score 0):

try creating a text node and adding it to element `f`
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp

if that isn't sufficient then try swapping out this line:

> f.setAttribute("id", "total"+i);

for this line:

> f.id = "total"+i;

references:

[setting the id attribute of an input element dynamically in IE: alternative for setAttribute method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851699/setting-the-id-attribute-of-an-input-element-dynamically-in-ie-alternative-for)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp

Comment: What I need is access the var f element by ID in my future code.